# NGSW caching Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, service-worker, angular6

**Problem:**

Unable to handle Firebase Storage urls in Angular6 service worker (presumably due to CORS).

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ {
      "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
      } ]
      }, {
      "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=7200"
      } ]
      }, {
      "source" : "404.html",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=300"
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

**ngsw-conf.json**

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png",
        "/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ],
    "urls": [
      "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/**"
    ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [{
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/some_route"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All files were uploaded to the Firebase Storage with following metadata:

```
{
  cacheControl: 'public,max-age=36000',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
}
```

When I load the app in Chrome or Opera, the app renders OK but I get error message 'Failed to load *some_firebase_storage_download_link* : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin *my_app_domain* is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.' and when I reload the app, no Firebase Storage resources are loaded.

When I load the app in Safari or Edge the app does not render at all and I get multiple console errors 'Failed to load resource'.

The app is being rendered and cached in Firefox without any issue.

When I omit the Firebase Storage and use only resources in Firebase Hosting, then the app is cached errorless in all browsers.

I have searched for setting the request's mode to 'no-cors', but failed to reach any resolution regarding my issue.

**UPDATE**

This might be caused by interference of NGSW and Firebase Firestore persistence handler (ie.: firebase.firestore().enablePersistence(); ). I am not sure how exactly Firebase Firestore persistence works, but when I initialise the app without Firestore persistence, then I am able to cache dynamic links from Firebase Storage. That is no use to me as I need both db and storage available at the same time.

Comment: You might try `gsutil cors set etc/cors.json gs://<my-project-name>.appspot.com`, where `etc/cors.json` includes `{ "origin": "*",  "method": "GET", "maxAgeSeconds": 3600}`. i can't imagine any connection to Firestore or persistence.

Comment: This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016609/angular7-service-worker-does-not-function-as-expected